# Transform table with records having multiple field values into a join table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Apologies in advance if the title and the question aren't clear - I started using Access 4 days ago and am only 1/10th of the way through the *Access 2016 Bible*.

To date I have been managing data in an excel worksheet which really belongs in a database. As such I've recently started the process of migrating into an Access 2016 database.

Currently the data are stored in a table/datasheet as follows:

```
CustomerID | InvoiceID
1          |  1 3 6 7 12 15
2          |  1 2 3
3          |  3 6 7
4          |  1 12 15
```

Each Customer ID is related to multiple Invoice IDs and each Invoice ID is related to multiple Customer IDs (a many-to-many relationship). The InvoiceID field is currently formatted as short text, and values are separated by a space.

I understand that to normalize this data, I should have 3 separate tables, e.g. A Customer Table, a Invoice Table and a Join Table which shows each link from a Customer to an Invoice in a one-to-one record.

Given this scenario, how best to turn my current table into the three tables? I've attempted to use a create table query, which I can get to work (for one customer at a time), but I'm not sure how to automate the process to save me manually creating ~40 queries.

Many thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings and welcome,

I think your proposal will work, the join table will have two fields, customer ID and invoice ID, probably indexed with duplicates, and then 2 master queries - Invoices with Customers and Customers with Invoices, that you can use in your other queries for reporting, etc. IF you need to do multiple joins, e.g. and customer to an invoice to all the customers on that invoice it might get a little messy.

Blair

Comment: Thanks for your comment Blair. I'm glad to hear that you agree with the proposed outcome, however I am looking for help specifically with the process - how to get from the table I have now, to the three tables the data should be in.